# Carousel or sliding view with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a sliding view to display some content bigger than the screen size. You can see the screenshot to better understand what i mean. The thing is that i'm using Bootstrap Framework for responsiveness & i would like to keep the content organised this way. Can you please give me some hints on how can i implement this ?Thanks[image]

Comment: Frankly, the screenshot only added a confusion.

Comment: why do you think so?